# Convert image to indexed color with custom palette through console

Tags: linux, console, imagemagick, gimp

I have image.png in truecolor,
palette.png (N colors, where N>256) or text file, where list RGB color palette.
How to get a picture with this palette?

If I use imagemagick:

```
convert image.png -remap palette.png remap_image.png
```

It does not work.

```
convert image.png -map palette.png remap_image.png
```

Gives a very bad quality. The image is very noisy. File size is bigger than before.

GIMP gives best quality:

```
Сonvert image to indexed color > use custom palette
```

But GIMP is GUI. I need to convert a lot images in the console without running the gimp and X.org.

Comment: A palette of "> 256" colors doesn't make sense - it will use RGB for each pixel = no palette. If you use "indexed color" in the GIMP, the result won't be truecolor but instead will use a palette of up to (<=) 256 colors. Is this what you want to do? Downsample "palette.png" to indexed colors, then map those to the png?

Comment: Yes, from RGB to palette will set independently. Need set correct quantity of colors.

Comment: Your -remap command will dither by default with FloydSteinberg. If you do not want that, put -dither none in front of -remap.

Answer (score 7):

Using a shared palette across *multiple* images requires a carefully crafted palette. If you don't take great care when using the palette of a single image across many images, the result will be poor.

This needn't be complicated though. If you have accesss to the GIMP (or other tool) which supports truecolor graphics, you can create a large image and fit all of the smaller images into it, then quantize the image to N colors, then use that palette as the source.

you should be able to closely mimic GIMP's behavior in the console using ImageMagick

Once you've got a truecolor image with all the colors you want to quantize,

```
# Create an 8-bit png from our source, with a 235-color palette as an example.
convert truecolor_source.png -colors 235 palette.png

# Create an 8-bit png from an arbitrary image and use the palette in palette.png
convert sample.png -map palette.png output.png
```

There are a number of options for down-sampling colors, like [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering#Digital_photography_and_image_processing). See [the ImageMagickv6](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#colors) example page for an excellent overview with example pictures and code.

Although I still don't *exactly* understand what you want to do, your currently most recent comment ("*Yes, from RGB to palette will set independently. Need set correct quantity of colors*"), it sounds like all you want to do is set a strict limit on the amount of colors of a bunch of images, but they don't need to use the *same* palette.

In that case, the solution is very simple:

```
convert sample.png -colors 135 output.png
```

Try playing with the quantization options if the result isn't to your satisfaction.

If the output image is too large for your liking, you can experiment with the `-quality` option.

If this still isn't satisfactory, please try to explain your goal in a more detailed manner.
Good luck!

Comment: Provide me with the source image(s) and explain exactly how you generated the results. First with convert, then with the gimp, so that I or someone else can reproduce the problem and see what gimp is doing differently.

Comment: It's an old post but I simply want to leave my 5 cents. I get the best compression for PNG using convert/mogrify when -quality set to 100

Answer (score 1):

cat photo.png | pngnq -s 1 > photoindexed.png

Answer (score 0):

I tend to get good results with the "-remap" (single imge) or "+remap" (multiple images) functions in combination with "-colors". Read up on those functions [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap). Note that "with "-remap" you provide IM with the final set of colors you want to use for the image, whether you plan to dither those colors, or just replace the ones with their nearest neighbours.", meaning just remapping/replacing might not look good enough, as colors from the input image are simply replaced by those from the palette image. Some form of dithering will be necessary to distribute pixel color conversion errors throughout the output image, because not all colors in the palette match those of the input image.
I'd suggest you use the "-colors N" option for that. This will reduce your output image color count to a maximum of N. By default ImageMagick uses "-dither Riemersma" for this implicitly when you specify "-colors N". The are also [other](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#dither_error) [dithering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#threshold) [options](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#ordered-dither) available.